# Dynamic Mod_Rewrite for unique auto generated links

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm wondering if this is possible -

I would like to use htaccess to simplify the links for my website as some users have complained about them looking 'spammy' - they are quite long currently.

I'm aware that it's possible for me to use something along these lines -

[website.com/subfolder/index.php/123456](http://website.com/subfolder/index.php/123456) into [website.com/123456](http://website.com/123456)

```
RewriteRule ^/123456$ /subfolder/index.php/123456
```

However my issue lies in that these links need to be dynamic. I've tried looking this up but the other similar questions I read are regarding making dynamic php links prettified and give specific answers.

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /subfolder/index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Testing this on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be (really nice site btw) with the input url `http://website.com/id/123456` gives `http://website.com/subfolder/index.php/id/123456` - this would be great if I can find a way to remove the /id/ from that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support `/123456` and `/id/123456` you can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]+/)?(\d{6})/?$ subfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

It will forward both URIs to `/subfolder/index.php/123456`

Due to use of `/d{6}/?$` in the pattern above it will only match URIs such as:

```
/123456
/123456/
/id/123456
/foobar/123456
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: Perfect my friend, I have one question, will your rule also rewrite such urls as 'website.com/guide/' or 'website.com/downloadlink.app/' ?

Comment: If it rewrites those url, its acceptable to use only `website.com/id/123456` but using `website.com/123456` is much more preferable

Comment: Those links I don't wish to rewrite - the dynamic links will always be numerical with 6 digits. I will accept your answer as correct answer as the RewriteRule works perfectly but can i ask that you please explain your answer as I dont wish to just 'copy/paste' working solution without understanding it :) does your rule have some checking in that pattern? you say it wont rewrite a url such as `website.com/downloadlink.app` how does it discern between these urls

Comment: I have added an explanation and exampled in answer, hope it clarifies.

Comment: fantastic, thank you :) +1 and accepted. I find it hard to find a article on the internet that properly explains the flags for the patterns such as ^$?/$ etc so thank you for the explanation

Comment: Thanks for accepting it. Have added some good references to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it, and I'm not sure this is the most optimal way, is to have a .htaccess in a subfolder, let's assume '/news', somewhat like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news.html?Path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now any request in '/news' will be redirected to '/news.html' with the url as an argument, but the visitor will only see the first. So, suppose the visitor asks for:

http://www.domain.com/news/happy_story.html

this will become, internally:

http://www.domain.com/news.html?Path=/news/happy_story.html

within this HTML page you can then use the `Path` argument to determine what to show. You can use several subfolders for different things.

Again, I don't know is this is the offical way to do it, but it works for me.

If there are many options you might wat to use a numbering system. Such a number could refer to an index in your database.

Since the first URL does not really refer to a page, a large part of it could be anything you want. Suppose you number your newsitems, and you use a URL like this:

http://www.domain.com/news/265/The_day_that_the_happy_news_was_annouced

In the background you only look for the number in the URL and you ignore the rest. So as long a the number is correct, the correct page will be shown. This URL would give the same result:

http://www.domain.com/news/265/Happy_story_day

And so on.

Comment: If you can use `$1` as a variable, would using something like: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]` not work with htaccess in root folder?

Comment: The problem with .htaccess in the root folder is that it will rewrite all your URL's. If that's what you want, then that's fine. You will have to read up on the rewrite rules to see what is possible, and what not. What I meant to say is that you don't need a rewrite rule for every page.

Comment: Hmm how about if i use the link website.com/id/123456.. Then i can use htaccess in the id subfolder.. Check my question, i'll update it with some 'nearly working' rules that are acceptable for me :)

Comment: Soo close, just need to find a way to remove the /id/ from final link!!

Answer (score 0):

KIKO's answer is a good one, as long as you publich URLs containing either part of your document path, or some database id.

If you want to do neither, create a "hub" page (just like those URL shorteners), where you look up some short URL in a database and do the redirect in PHP.

So say you create a news article with the headline "Some happy Story! With some über crap/garbage chars in it", you clean the string, store it along with your real article url, in some database:

```
| short_url                              | long_url                                   |
| "some_happy_story_with_some_uber_crap" | "http://website.com/news/article.php/1234" |
```

That way you can also have a couple of short URLs pointing to the same article (eg some stripping stop words from the "official" URL).

In hub.php (which can also be covered by some RewriteRule), you

```
SELECT long_url FROM urls WHERE short_url='<script_path>'
```

or similiar, and issue a

```
header("Redirect: ".$long_url); exit;
```

Comment: Please check my updated question - I'm reasonably confident I can achieve this without having to resort to a PHP redirect